# Apply transformation matrix to existing frame

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says, I have a frame, which comes by default in the Kinect, and then I calculated a 4x4 transformation matrix. How can I apply it to the existing frame?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289144/apply-transformation-matrix-to-existing-frame/) by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest method is to create a new frame that is the transformed Kinect frame. You can then use that frame throughout your system.

You can create a new frame from your transformation matrix and broadcast it using tf2. See [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) for how to broadcast a transform. If the transform will never change, you can also follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) to broadcast a static frame. (There's also a [tutorial specifically about adding a new frame](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29), but it's much the same as the broadcast frame tutorial.)

To create the frame from your transformation matrix, you need to convert it to tf2's [`Matrix3x3` type](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Matrix3x3.html) for the rotation part and a Vector3 for the translation part. From that, you can construct a `tf2::Transform` object, passing the matrix into the constructor. That can then be converted to the message data type for broadcasting using the [`tf2::fromMsg()` function](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2/html/namespacetf2.html#a5e395779f27ef64653d748ecae342954)

```
tf2::Matrix3x3 tm(xx, xy, xz, yx, yy, yz, zx, zy, zz);
tf2::Vector3 translation(x, y, z);
tf2::Transform trans(tm, translation);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped new_frame;
new_frame.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
new_frame.header.frame_id = "kinect_frame_name";
new_frame.child_frame_id = "transformed_kinect";
new_frame.transform = tf2::toMsg(trans);
```

If you know the Euler rotation angles originally used to create the transformation matrix, then another option is to convert them to a quaternion and put that into the message's `transform` member.

On the other hand, if you want to use the transformed frame locally only, you can get the pose of the Kinect frame, convert it to a `tf2::Transform` object using the `tf2::fromMsg()` function. This will convert a `geometry_msgs::Pose` to a `tf2::Transform`. You can then convert your 4x4 transformation matrix to another `tf2::Transform` object, [multiply them together](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Transform.html#a4ea68353243d638eb98ea2742fe72db2) to get the resulting transformation from the origin of the frame you original got the Kinect frame relative to, and that's the pose of your transformed Kinect frame.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thank you very much for your detailed response. I'm trying to apply everything you told me but I can't help but notice that the last part is ideal for me. Isn't there a way to subscribe to that tf, save it somewhere and multiply it with the transformation matrix and then publish the new one?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-04-20**:
That's what the first part does.

**Comment by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thanks, it worked perfectly ^^